# How to run webdriver then protractor through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, webdriver, protractor

I would like to run my protractor tests through a batch file.
To do it I need to first run webdriver-manager start then run protractor conf.js.
However I have tried to do this in one batch file I did no work as webdriver manager starts but not protractor.
Here is the two batch file I used :

Webdriver.bat :

```
set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set webdriver=%BASE_DIR%\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules
call %webdriver%\.bin\webdriver-manager start
uxsleep 5
call protractor
```

Protractor.bat :

```
set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set webdriver=%BASE_DIR%\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules
%webdriver%\.bin\protractor ..\%BASE_DIR%\e2e\protractor.conf.js
```

Is there any way to run webdriver-manager then protractor with one click?

Answer (score 0):

Windows supports Unix's `&` operator. You can do this in cmd.exe:

```
Webdriver.bat & Protractor.bat
```